# Как обновлять количество пользователей в Wordpress с помощью ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://wordpress/",
        // success: function( data ) {
        //     document.getElementById('qua').innerHTML="<?php echo $result['total_users']; ?>";
        // }

        success : function(){                  
                  setInterval(function(){
                  document.getElementById('qua').innerHTML="<?php echo $result['total_users']; ?>";
                  // alert();
                }, 10000);
         }
    });

// });
</script>
```

Мне нужно обновлять количество постов без перезагрузки страницы. Я решил начать с простого---количества пользователей. Алерт работает,но количество пользователей не меняется пока не перезагружу страницу

Comment: как у вас выполняется эта строка `document.getElementById('qua').innerHTML="<?php echo $result['total_users']; ?>";`? в браузере пхп-код?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, у тебя в коде не совсем понятно что.

Могу пояснить на пальцах как можно легко реализовать ajax в wordpress

Создай страницу, дай ей слаг (например ajax), создай шаблон этой страницы (page-ajax.php)

```js
//Тут ставим действие или событие по которому мы будем отправлять запрос на нашу страницу
//не обязательно использовать таймер 
setTimeout(function () { 
    //Раз мы работает с JQUERY, то используем JQUERY
    //Первым параметром передаем адрес нашей страницы, а вторым параметром callback функцию которая примет то, что мы напишем в шаблоне page-ajax
    $.post('/ajax', function(data){
        alert(data);
    });

}, 1000);
```

```php
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  echo $wpdb->get_var("select count(*) from wp_users"); //У тебя может отличатся название таблицы, если оно не wp_users, замени.
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: Вопрос решил, а заминусовали. Странно) надеюсь я вам помог, пожалуйста, обращайтесь

Comment: Может случайно,извините)

Comment: Ничего страшного. Спасибо. Сам недавно разбирался с ajax в wordpress и понял что лучше все запросы слать на 1 страницу, а уже внутри обрабатывать. Это удобнее чем 100500 хуков в functions.php